# How to allow special characters with OWASP HTML Sanitizer?

Tags: java, xss, sanitization, owasp

I am using the OWASP Html Sanitizer to prevent XSS attacks. I am using spring boot application, and jackson to map json to java object. For one of my json field email, While converting json to java object , I am getting encoded value for @ at my controller. so @ will be replaced with '& hash 64;'

Comment: If you disable OWASP html sanitizer, is it still escaped?

Comment: Where are you using the sanitizer? It shouldn't be run at all on JSON data